# NPM not working on SMB share, getting permission errors

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, smb

I'm trying to run a `npm install` on an SMB share (which I have full read and write permissions to), but it keeps giving me the following:

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EACCES: permission denied, open '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EACCES: permission denied, open '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/node_modules/tslib/modules'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/crc32/node_modules/tslib/modules'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/node_modules/tslib/test'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/node_modules/tslib/test'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EACCES: permission denied, open '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/isomorphic-fetch/node_modules/webidl-conversions/LICENSE.md'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EACCES: permission denied, open '/Volumes/Stuff 48 TB/Shared/BraixenBot/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/build/uint32ArrayFrom.js.map'

added 19 packages, removed 32 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 342 packages in 6s

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

7 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I am running macOS 12.6.8 on the computer I am trying to run the `npm install` at, and the SMB is running on an Asustor NAS. I already tried running chmod 775 on the node_modules folder, but it made no difference.